# how to Use LocalStorage with Angular

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

I have created a small application to add data to a list and calculate the total; however, i want to leverage local storage to prevent loosing data on page refresh. This is what I have tried to no avail. Any insight would be awesome!

```
  angular.module('list', [])

.controller('RecordCtrl', function($scope){

    // Historical data
    $scope.history = [];

    // Default data (can be loaded from a database)
    $scope.records = [

    ];

   forEach(values in localStorage){
    var newValue = JSON.parse(localStorage[values]);
    $scope.records.push(newValue);

    }
    // Total prices
    $scope.Totals = function () {
        var priceTotal = 0;



        angular.forEach($scope.records, function (record) {

                priceTotal += (record.price * record.qty);


        });

        // Return aggregate data
        return { price: priceTotal };
    };

    // Delete data
    $scope.Delete = function (index) {
        // Remove first / oldest element from history if it reaches maximum capacity of 10 records
        if ($scope.history.length === 10)
            $scope.history.shift();
        // Add deleted record to historical records
        $scope.history.push($scope.records[index]);

        // Remove from main records (using index)
        $scope.records.splice(index, 1);
    };

    // Reset new data model
    $scope.Reset = function () {
        $scope.newDescription = '';
        $scope.newQty = 0;
        $scope.newPrice = 0;
        $scope.newComment = '';
    };
    $scope.Reset();

    // Add new data
    $scope.Add = function () {
        // Do nothing if no state is entered (blank)
        if (!$scope.newDescription )
            return;

        var newHardware = {
            description: $scope.newDescription,
            qty: $scope.newQty,
            price: $scope.newPrice,
            comment: $scope.newComment
        };
        localStorage.setItem("values" + localStorage.length, JSON.stringify(newHardware));

        $scope.records.push(newHardware);


        /*
        // Add to main records
        $scope.records.push({
            description: $scope.newDescription ,
            qty: $scope.newQty,
            price: $scope.newPrice,
            comment: $scope.newComment
        });
        */
        // See $Scope.Reset...
        $scope.Reset();
    };

    // Undo action (delete)
    $scope.Undo = function () {
        // Add last / most recent historical record to the main records
        $scope.records.push($scope.history[ $scope.history.length - 1 ]);

        // Remove last / most recent historical record
        $scope.history.pop();
    };


});
```

Comment: what variable do you want to store in localStorage?

Comment: im using ng-repeat to list out the $scope.records array.

Comment: so you want to store `$scope.records` on change and load it on page load, right?

Comment: The items added to $scope.records i want to be stored on refresh yes.

Comment: `records` a model, according to MV* pattern, and should act as single source of truth. Wrap `records` into a service and sync data with localStorage inside.

Comment: I have a from with 4 input fields. After adding the values it populates out to a table. so those values I would like to try and store even after the page refreshes. I hope im not unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$scope.$watchCollection` to trigger a save action to local storage.

---

Online Demo - **https://plnkr.co/edit/uEVND2WRIZ61RtRTK5l1?p=preview**

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add()">add record</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">clear</a>
  </h1>
  <pre>{{records | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

**javascript**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {

  $scope.records = storageGet('records', []);

  $scope.add = function() {

    var record = {
      name: new Date().getTime() // just for the demo
    };

    $scope.records.push(record);
  };

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.records = [];
  };


  $scope.$watchCollection('records', function() {
    storageSet('records', $scope.records);
  }, true);


  function storageSet(key, value) {
    $window.localStorage[key] = angular.toJson(value);
  }

  function storageGet(key, defaultValue) {
    var value = $window.localStorage[key];


    if (value === undefined) {
      return defaultValue;
    }

    return angular.fromJson(value);
  }

});
```